# Google Apps Script: trigger text file download in script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I've written a short script in the Google Apps Script online editor to read my Google Calendar events for a particular day and determine when I am available. The goal is to produce some text that I can copy into a scheduling email, like this:

- 1/6, 10:00-11:30am EST
- 1/6, 12:45-3:00pm EST
- 1/6, 4:00-5:30pm EST

I can log these lines and then view logs in the web interface, but the log entries have these awkward timestamps at the beginning that I have to remove manually after copying. For example:

- [19-01-04 21:51:48:835 PST] 1/6, 10:00-11:30am EST
- [19-01-04 21:51:48:836 PST] 1/6, 12:45-3:00pm EST
- [19-01-04 21:51:48:836 PST] 1/6, 4:00-5:30pm EST

As a workaround, I would like my script to write the lines to a text file and then download this file to my computer. Answers to similar questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281272/initiate-a-download-from-google-apps-script), involve **SpreadsheetApp** objects (I'm using the Calendar, not Sheets, API) and creating UI elements (I'd like to do this without a UI). Can I trigger such a download directly in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of or as well as logging to the console, you could use

```
var body = '';

// Under each console log statement, use
body += loggedData + "\n";

// Change 'loggedData' for the appropriate variable, etc.

MailApp.sendEmail('you@yourdomain.com', 'subject', body);
```

---

**EDIT**

You could take it a step further and create a draft email with the data already in it.

```
GmailApp.createDraft('', 'subject', body);
```

You can add the recipient from Gmail when accessing your drafts. (You may have to refresh the page to see it).

Comment: That's a good workaround -- certainly solves the problem. Thank you for your help!