# Download just created file from Google Drive to local

Tags: google-apps-script, download, google-drive-api

I use this code to generate a XML file on my Google Drive :

```
var nomFichierXML = "CazaAzul_CSI_"+AccountingPeriod+"_"+DateDuJour
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(xml, 'application/xml', 'CSI.xml');
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID");
blob.setName(nomFichierXML+".xml");
folder.createFile(blob);
```

I would like to download this file automatically on my local computer just after the "folder.creatFile(blob)" function.

I managed to creat the URL of this filw with this command :

```
var fileId = file.getId();
var urlCSI = file.getDownloadUrl()
```

But after that... I'm stuck.

Comment: Are you looking to trigger a download popup or just create the file directly in some local folder? In the first case you'll probably need to [display the link somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281272/initiate-a-download-from-google-apps-script) so the user clicks it. For the second case, Apps Script runs server side and it doesn't have access to your local files so you can't do it.

Comment: Hello, a simple trigger would be perfect. I will read the post your sent to me. Thank's !

Comment: Saddyl UiApp doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: The OP's post is deprecated but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69548483/12306687) has more recent info.