# How to save a file from within Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to download html and save it to a local file using Google Apps Script.

Here is the code:

```
function save_url(url, filename) {
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  // None of the following work.
  DocsList.createFile(fileName, html);
  jobFolder.createFile(filename, html, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
  DriveApp.createFile(filename, html);

  return txt;

}
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you kindly provide the precise error you are encountering? Additionally, please note that the `DocsList` class appears to be deprecated. When tested in the Google Apps Script editor, it results in the error message: `ReferenceError: DocsList is not defined`.

Lastly, for the sake of clarity, is your primary objective to download the HTML and store it in your Google Drive, or are you aiming to save it as a local file on your computer?

Comment: `jobFolder` and `txt` are both undefined

Comment: Why don't you just download the html file with GDrive and be done with it?

Comment: Try [Dr-Brackets solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69548483/7215091)